# How do I turn Django Multislelect checkbox fields into clickable buttons?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, multi-select

Trying to create each of the fields/moods as clickable buttons.

For example: Similar to this answer on stack overflow, just with the ability to click multiple buttons. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55873783/11660747

Not looking to make it a dropdown menu, as I want all the buttons to be visible at once.
This is what I have so far...

````
 <b>What are you feeling?</b><br>  Please choose at least one mood for best results. 

<br>
    {% for x in form.visible_fields.7%}

    <div>

     {{ x }}

  </div>
   {% endfor %}```
````

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display them all at the same time you can do something like the following

`forms.py`

```py
class FeelingsForm(forms.Form):
    OPTIONS = (
        ('1', 'Happy'),
        ('2', 'Sad'),
        ('3', 'Angry')
    )
    Feelings = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
                                          choices=OPTIONS)
```

This will give you something that looks like

[image: options]

You can get rid of the dots if you loop through each checkbox

```py
<b>What are you feeling?</b>
<br>
Please choose at least one mood for best results. 
<br>
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}

    <div>

     {% for feeling in field %}
        <p>{{ feeling }}</p>
     {% endfor %}

    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

[image: options without list dots]

Comment: I would like them to not have the checkbox and only look like a button with the name of the field on the button.